# which is best module for marketplace in drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

I have to create  marketplace where a user can create content and other users have to pay to view this publish content . I am confused between ubercart and drupal commerce . Do you know 
which is best to use from these two modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [great comparison](http://cms.about.com/od/drupal-modules/a/Ubercart-Vs-Drupal-Commerce-Which-Should-You-Choose.htm) of the two.

This is a good option should you choose Commerce as [Commerce Kickstart](https://commerceguys.com/product/commerce-kickstart) it sets up a lot of the common configurations that you'll need and be setting up anyway.

I find Commerce to be more flexible and have greater support when it comes to UI, managing products and payment configurations.